# I just downloaded py and vscode, my first time using both, but then this appear "Python was not found; run without arguments to install from the ..."

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, runtime-error

I downloaded py and vscode, they were working good yesterday, but today when I open, and I only tried to print something else, it appear this error "Python was not found; run without arguments to install from the Microsoft Store, or disable this shortcut from Settings > Manage App Execution Aliases."
I desinstalled both and install them again, installing py i check de path bottom, and I alredy download the extension of py in vscode, and it is still no working.

Comment: Seems there's somthing wrong with your local python environment. Do you add Python to PATH? Try adding it then see if the question goes away.

Comment: Open **Command Palette--> Python: Select Interpreter**--> enter the interpreter path. Manually select `python.exe`, can you get python interpreter shown in status bar?

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure you check the **"Add python to path"** option before installing python. And then restart the system, that is how I solved my problem. And if it still does not, please follow the [@J.R.BEATS answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69747546/14048071).

[image: please check this option while installing]

Comment: Welcome to SO! From the OP's question, they stated they did try uninstalling and reinstalling with the "Add Python to path" option checked.

Answer (score 0):

I use to have it too. You should honestly use Pycharm. Pycharm gives less problems than vscode.

You can try:

1. Check your Python version and be sure it is installed on your machine
2. Check the path environment variable
3. Go to -> "start" and type "Manage App Execution Aliases". Go to it and turn off "Python"

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv. You can install "local" versions of Python and have different environments.

> Pyenv lets you easily switch between multiple versions of Python

Answer (score -1):

If someone encounters the same problem and after trying all the solutions mentioned above, they need to modify the vscode .json file in the "code-runner.executorMap" section. They should modify the value of the "python" key, instead of having "python": "python3" they should put "python": "python".